# Xpath - evaluate function returns javax.xml.transform.TransformerException

Tags: java, xml, xpath

This is the first time I am using XPath, and I am trying to query a very basic example.

```
    String xml = "<resp><status>good</status><msg>hi</msg></resp>";

    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

    String status = "";
    try {
        status = (String) xpath.evaluate("//resp/status", source,XPathConstants.STRING);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("status=" + status);
```

I receive the following exception:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at Heandlers.HTTP.x(HTTP.java:74)   at
>   Views.Main.main(Main.java:15) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to evaluate expression using this context  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 5 more
>   --------- java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at Heandlers.HTTP.x(HTTP.java:74)   at
>   Views.Main.main(Main.java:15)
>   --------------- linked to ------------------ javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException:
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate
>   expression using this context     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at Heandlers.HTTP.x(HTTP.java:74)   at
>   Views.Main.main(Main.java:15) Caused by:
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate
>   expression using this context     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate
>   expression using this context     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 5 more status=

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're using an invalid `InputSource`, e.g. `org.w3c.css.sac.InputSource`. Make sure you've imported `org.xml.sax.InputSource`.

Comment: In my case it was import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource instead of org.xml.sax.InputSource